# How to count records by day from specific hour in a range of date using SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a datetime field and I want to count all records by day from hour 8:00 to 9:00 in a range of date (i.e: from: 01/01/2012 to: 01/03/2012).

for instance, if I have the below data:

```
2012-01-01 08:26
2012-01-01 08:40
2012-01-01 09:26
2012-01-01 10:26
2012-01-02 08:06
2012-01-02 09:26
2012-01-02 09:40
2012-01-03 08:30
2012-01-03 10:26
```

the result should look like this:

```
2012-01-01 2
2012-01-02 1
2012-01-03 1
```

EDIT:
Here is what I got using @gbn solution (it works for me)

```
SELECT    COUNT(*),  convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101)
FROM    tblSingleBox (nolock)
WHERE    DATEPART(Hour, scandate) = 8
    and (scandate>='01/03/2012' and scandate<'01/05/2012')
GROUP BY    convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101) 
order by convert(varchar(10),ScanDate,101)
```

Comment: you mean 08:00:00.000 to 08:59:59.999? That is, is 09:00 inclusive?

Comment: sql server 2005, and yes 8-8:59:59

Comment: @Somebody - just note that this tight query (which is totally correct) Does still *scan* every record in the date-range.  If you want a faster query, you can get that from a *seek* instead, but with a more complex query.

Comment: @Dems thank you so much for the tip, I gave you a vote up, for your suggestion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SQL Server 2005 and earlier

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*),
   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, SomeDateTime), 0)
   -- SQL Server 2008: CAST(SomeDateTime AS date)
FROM
   SomeTable
WHERE
   DATEPART(Hour, SomeDateTime) = 8
GROUP BY
   DATEADD(dd, DATEDIFF(dd, 0, SomeDateTime), 0);
   -- SQL Server 2008: CAST(SomeDateTime AS date);
```

MySQL:

```
SELECT
   COUNT(*),
   DATE(SomeDateTime)
FROM
   SomeTable
WHERE
   HOUR(SomeDateTime) = 8
GROUP BY
   DATE(SomeDateTime);
```

Comment: if you filter just for the hour, it will count all days in that specific hour

Comment: thanks, but I need also that for a range of date, how can I do that?

Comment: @gbn - I assume this is going to need a full scan (table or index) rather than seeks?  Due to the DATEPART() use?

Comment: @Dems: correct. Short of a computed column I don't see a better way without other artefacts

Comment: @Somebody: add more conditions to the WHERE clause

Comment: @gbn - Join on a calendar table as per my answer?

Comment: @gbn look my edit comment, so, by using DATEPART(hour,somedatetime)=8 covers the range from 8-8:59:59 ? thanks

Answer (score 2):

In this case the simplest code and the fastest code will likely vary a lot, and possibly be dependent on the size of your data set.

I suspect the fastest would be to join on a calendar and filter.  In this case I'll make a calendar before I start, but I suggest a permanent one...

```
CREATE TABLE #calendar (
  date AS DATETIME
)
INSERT INTO #calendar SELECT '2011-12-31' UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-01'
            UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-02' UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-03'
            UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-04' UNION ALL SELECT '2012-01-05'

SELECT
  calendar.date,
  COUNT(*)
FROM
  yourTable
INNER JOIN
  #calendar    AS calendar
    ON  yourTable.DateTimeField >= calendar.date + @minTime
    AND yourTable.DateTimeField <  calendar.date + @maxTime
WHERE
      calendar.date >= @startDate
  AND calendar.date <= @endDate
GROUP BY
  calendar.date
```

This should yield the most index friendly query, and so for any reasonable size of data be very efficient.

**NOTE:**

The `calendar.date + @Time` sections will vary.  You just said MS SQL Server, so it would be more like...

```
    ON  yourTable.DateTimeField >= DATEADD(hour, @minHour, calendar.date)
    AND yourTable.DateTimeField <  DATEADD(hour, @maxHour, calendar.date)
```

Comment: This avoids using DATEPART() and other functions to yield the `index friendly query`.  This means that only the relevant portions of the index are processed, rather than scanning the whole index or table.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server 2005

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb.dbo.#DATES') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #DATES

CREATE TABLE #DATES
    (   LogDate smalldatetime   )

INSERT INTO #DATES
    (   LogDate )
            SELECT  '2012-01-01 08:26'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-01 08:40'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-01 09:26'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-01 10:26'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-02 08:06'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-02 09:26'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-02 09:40'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-03 08:30'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-03 10:26'
UNION SELECT '2012-01-03 15:26'

DECLARE @nStartHour smallint
DECLARE @nEndHour smallint

SET @nStartHour = 15
SET @nEndHour = 16

SELECT  CONVERT(varchar, LogDate, 101), COUNT(*)
FROM        #DATES
WHERE       DATEPART(hour,LogDate) BETWEEN @nStartHour AND (@nEndHour - 1)
GROUP BY CONVERT(varchar, LogDate, 101)
```